# how to write select query using if condition,And condition and where condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

HI CI developers i am new to Ci so request you people to help me in developing a project which i had already developed using core php. So now i am interested to learn codeigniter so trying to develop same matrimonial project using ci framework. In core php i had written a search query which now i want to write it CI format so please help me guys
**THIS IS MY HTML PAGE**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>searchresult/users" method="post">
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content" >
**strong text** 
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
<tr>
  <td>Looking for</td> 
  <td> <input type="radio" name="look" id="look" value="female" checked="checked"/> 
     <span style="color:#000000;">Bride</span> 
     <input type="radio" name="look" id="look" value="male" />
     <span style="color:#000000;"> Groom</span>
  </td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td>Age</td> 
  <td> <span style="color:#000000;">From </span> 
    <select name="age_from" id="age" class="inp_age" > 
       <option>21</option> <option>22</option> 
       <option>23</option> <option>24</option> 
       <option>25</option> <option>26</option>
      </select>
   <span style="color:#000000;">&nbsp; To</span>
   <select name="age_to" id="age" class="inp_age" > 
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option> 
    <option >20</option>
    <option selected="selected">70</option> 
   </select>
  </td>
</tr>
 <tr> 
   <td>Sect</td> 
   <td><select name="sect" id="sect" onchange="return SelectSect(this.value);" class="inp_search" >
 <!-- <select name="cont" id="cont" onchange="return SelectState(this.value);" class="inp">--> 
 <option value="">Any sect</option>
 <option value="<?php echo $sects['sect_id'];?>"><?php echo $sects['sect_name'];?></option> 
</select>
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Sub Sect</td> 
    <td>
      <select name="subsect" id="subsect" onchange="return SelectSub(this.value);" class="inp_search" > 
       <option value="">Any subsect</option> 
    </select>
   </td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
     <td>Country</td>
     <td> 
         <select name="country" id="country" onchange="return SelectState(this.value);" class="inp_search"> 
          <option value="">Any Country</option> 
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id'];?>" style="width:10px"><?php echo $country['Country_name'];?></option>
        </select>
      </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
     <td>State</td> 
     <td>
         <select name="state" id="state" onchange="return SelectCity(this.value);" class="inp_search" > 
          <option value="">Any state</option>
         </select>
     </td>
  </tr> 
   <tr>
      <td>City</td> 
      <td>
         <select name="city" id="city" class="inp_search" > 
            <option value="">Any city</option>
       </select>
      </td> 
   </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Qualification</td>
        <td>
            <select name="qualification" id="qualification" class="inp_search" > 
              <option value="">Any qualification</option> 
              <option value="<?php echo $qualifications['qualification_id'];?>"><?php echo $qualifications['qualification'];?></option> 
            </select>
        </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
        <td> <div style="padding-left:100px;">
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button green search_btn" value="Search" />
            </div>
       </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

**THIS IS MY CONTROLLER PAGE**

```
 <?php 
  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Searchresult extends CI_Controller { 
       public function __construct(){ 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->model('searchresultss','','TRUE');
       } 
       public function users() {
         $this->load->view('includes/kheader');
         $data['showdata'] = $this->searchresultss->login();
         $this->load->view('searchresult',$data);
         $this->load->view('includes/khelp'); 
         $this->load->view('includes/kfooter'); }
     }
```

**THIS MY MODEL PAGE**

```
  <?php 
  Class Searchresultss extends CI_Model {  
      function login() { 
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this -> db -> from('users'); 
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $query; 
       }
  } 
  **this i smy core php query**
    $per_page =3; 
    $members=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE if('$se_ct'!='',sect = '$se_ct' AND
    if('$subsect' !='',subsect = '$subsect',subsect like '%%'),sect like '%%' AND  
    subsect like '%%') AND IF( '$cou_ntry' !='', country = '$cou_ntry' AND if('$sta_te' 
    !='', state = '$sta_te' AND if('$ci_ty' !='',city = '$ci_ty',city like '%%'),state 
    LIKE '%%' AND city LIKE '%%'), country LIKE '%%' AND state LIKE '%%' AND city LIKE 
    '%%' ) AND age >= '$age_from' AND age <= '$age_to' AND IF('$qualification' 
    !='',qualification = '$qualification', qualification LIKE '%%' ) AND gender = 
    '$look' And status='1' "); 
   $count =mysql_num_rows($members);
   $pages =ceil($count/$per_page);
```

i need $count and $pages result too so guys help me in writing controller and model for above given details

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to query directly:

```
function login( $per_page = 3 ) { // it will need all the variables too included in your query
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE if('$se_ct'!='',sect = '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect = '$subsect',subsect like '%%'),sect like '%%' AND subsect like '%%') AND IF( '$cou_ntry' !='', country = '$cou_ntry' AND if('$sta_te' !='', state = '$sta_te' AND if('$ci_ty' !='',city = '$ci_ty',city like '%%'),state LIKE '%%' AND city LIKE '%%'), country LIKE '%%' AND state LIKE '%%' AND city LIKE '%%' ) AND age >= '$age_from' AND age <= '$age_to' AND IF('$qualification' !='',qualification = '$qualification', qualification LIKE '%%' ) AND gender = '$look' And status='1' ";
    $data               = array();
    $query              = $this->db->query( $query );
    $data['results']    = $query->result();
    $data['count']      = $query->num_rows();
    $data['pages']      = ceil($count/$per_page);
    return $data; 
}
```

Comment: To convert it in CI format, cut your where clause, put it in a variable and pass it to the `$this->db->where($where, false)` clause. Here, `$where` is the `where clause string` of your query.

Comment: Thanks Nil'z but i getting below error                                A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: look,age_from,age_to,se_ct,subsect,coun_try,sta_te,ci_ty,qualification,count
Filename: controllers/searchresult.php
Line Number:29...so on                                                       please me help me out

Comment: CI developers help me out in solving the issue

Comment: Have you checked the answer carefully bro? have you seen the comment? it states clearly that you need to pass all the variable in your function that your query is using?